# Facebook JS SDK send private message parameters issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook JS SDK. In my below coding picture argument is not working. So, my private message link picture is hidden and also not working the description parameter.

But, in airbnb.com site private message display the full logo image.

```
   FB.init({ 
       appId:'<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>', 
       frictionlessRequests: true
     });
function send_invitation(){
     FB.ui(
     { 
      method: 'send',
      link: '<?php echo base_url()."users/signup?airef=".$referral_code;?>',
      picture: '<?php echo base_url()."images/logo.png";?>',
     }, requestCallback);
      function requestCallback(response) {

      }       
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'picture' parameter of the send dialog - the documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

The image attached to the link is the same one that [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) detects on the URL via the meta tags (if provided) or by scraping the images from the HTML (if no meta tags are provided)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question. How to set the meta tag og:image. In your mentioned Facebook's Debug Tool display the multiple og:images. Kindly clarify it.

Comment: You put the meta tags in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML and Facebook's crawler detects them when the link is shared or you use the debug tool

Comment: I use the meta tag og:image but meta tag og image is not displaying. It display the largest image from the multiple of og images. and Facebook's Debug Tool doesn't display the Raw Open Graph Document Information.